# How Order by field located in another table (Many-to-Many Relation) using Linq functions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three tables :

**Projects:**
ProjectID ,
ProjectName

**ProjectPart:(FKs table)**
ProjectID ,
PartsID

**Parts:**
PartsID ,
PartsName

How can I order **Project** Table according to **PartsName** field in **Parts** Table using linq function ?

here's the code I tried, but I couldn't figure out how to continue with it.

```
Project projectList = projectList.OrderBy(s =>s.ProjectParts.Select(a => a.Parts.PartsName).ToList());
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you have tried?

Comment: @CodeNotFound please recheck

Comment: What is porjectList? Just the Projects? And you want only the fields from Projects? (if so the lowest value in parts -PartsName- specify how the ProjectNames would be sorted?). A sample output would be nice.

Comment: Let's say you have 4 projects. Project 1 with parts "B" and "D". Project 2 with parts "A" and "E". Project 3 with part "C". Project 4 without any parts. What order do you expect these products to be sorted in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't reply and show exactly what you wanted, I would assume you only want results from Projects and you want them sorted by their partsName used:

```
var projects = ctx.Projects
    .OrderBy(p => p.ProjectParts.OrderBy(pp => pp.Parts.PartsName)
                   .First().Parts.PartsName)
    .ThenBy(p => p.ProjectName);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each project can have many parts.  Which part of the many do you want to use in the sorting?  How about the first one?

```
from project in ctx.Projects
let part = project.ProjectParts.First().Part
order by part.PartsName
select new {project, part}
```